# Check bad word in string from a array file txt

Tags: php, arrays

```
$badwords = array('Hello' => 1, 'aa' => 1, 'vv' => 1);  

$string = "Hello how are you";

$words = explode(' ', $string);
foreach($words as $word) {
        $word = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]*/', '', $word);
        if (isset($badwords[$word])) {
            echo("Found $word<br>");
        }else{
            echo("ok $word<br>");
        }
}
```

i trying to get words from txt file and put all in array and check but i cant...
can you help me? thanks.

ask: i want to check word in string from txt file...

Comment: What do you want to happen, exactly?

Comment: i want to convert txt with bad words in array and then check if exist in string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use trim like this way.

```
$badwords = array('Hello' => 1, 'aa' => 1, 'vv' => 1);  

    $string = "Hello, how are you";

    $words = explode(' ', $string);
        foreach($words as $word) {
        $word = trim($word, " ,.!?");
        if (isset($badwords[$word])) {
            echo("Found $word<br>");
        }else{
            echo("ok $word<br>");
    }
        }
```

test code:

```
<?php
$badwords = array('Hello' => 1, 'aa' => 1, 'vv' => 1);

$string = "Hello, how are you";

$words = explode(' ', $string);
foreach($words as $word) {
    $word = trim($word, " ,.!?");
    if (isset($badwords[$word])) {
        echo("Found $word<br>");
        echo "\n";
    }else{
        echo("ok $word<br>");
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
Found Hello<br>
ok how<br>
ok are<br>
ok you<br>
```

edited:

```
<?php
$badwords = file("aaa.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$badwords = array_flip($badwords);

$string = "Hello how are you";

$words = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach($words as $word) {
    if (isset($badwords[$word])) {
        echo("Found $word<br>");
        echo "\n";
    }else{
        echo("ok $word<br>");
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

aaa.txt:

```
Hello
aa
vv
```

output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
Found Hello<br>
ok how<br>
ok are<br>
ok you<br>
```

Comment: @NoeNazza why you omit the trim code

Comment: my question is another, help me.

Comment: i want to convert txt file with badwords into ARRAY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @NoeNazza I suppose you stroe badword in the way  like aaa.txt in my answer, check it.

Answer (score 0):

> i trying to get words from txt file and put all in array and check but
>   i cant... can you help me?

To read a txt file to an `array` use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

```
$lines = file('/path/to/file.txt');
// $lines is an array and contains all lines of the txt file, loop it:
foreach($lines as $line)
{
  $words = explode(' ', $line);
  foreach($words as $word)
  {
     // implement your logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you write all code?... i try but not work.

Comment: No, we don't write "all code" around here.